# Mysql for each row check to use if a field is in another table and if not delete that row

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, each

I have two tables, first one is called 'users' and the second is called 'profiles'. Both tables have a field called 'id', the profiles table also has a field called 'user_id' which I use to join the two tables. Long story short when users are deleted their profiles are not (that problem has been fixed), I would like to find all the profile in the profile table that don't have a user connected to them. I need to somehow check each row in the profile table to see if the 'user_id' field exists in the 'users' table under the field 'id' and if it does not delete the row in the profile table that contains that 'user_id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from profiles p
where not exists (select 1 from users u where p.profile_id = u.id);
```

If you want to delete the rows:

```
delete p from profiles p
where not exists (select 1 from users u where p.profile_id = u.id);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much this is exactly what I needed, if you don't mind me asking, what does  'p' and 'u' stand for?  ('profiles p') ,('users u') , ('p.profile_id') and ('u.id')

Comment: @HelpmeJohn . . . Those are table aliases.  They are used here just as abbreviations for the table names, so the query is easier to write and read.